# How to print single chars from 2D arrays

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char

I'm trying to print out an empty tic tac toe table but when the program reaches the second for loop it crashes.

```
void pBoard(char board[3][3])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    printf("  0 1 2");
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){
        printf("\n%d ", i); //After this it crashes
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j){
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints

```
        0 1 2
      0
```

Edit: The comment system doesn't seem to be letting me format the code the same way I do here. I called the function with

```
 while(choice != 'P'){
        pBoard(board[3][3]);
        player = 'X';
        play(board[3][3], player);
        if (checkWinner(board[3][3])){
            break;
        }
        player = 'O';
        play(board[3][3], player);
        if (checkWinner(board[3][3])){
            break;
        }
    }
```

Size is defined as 3.

I get an error message in the middle of execution.

Comment: Please show with which parameter you call `pBoard`, and how `SIZE` is defined.

Comment: When you say "crashes" do you get a stack trace or error message/code?

Comment: Edited post since commenting is weird

Comment: You need to outline what an empty board would look like. For example, an empty slot could be filled with a *space* character. This way, when printing your board with just a single move made, you would have a 2D output with a single `X` at some coordinate, and the rest would be *space* characters.

Comment: Otherwise, `pBoard` works as expected. You can test this with the board: `char board[3][3] = {'X', 'O', ' ', 'O', 'X', 'O', ' ', 'O', ' '};`, whereby invoking `pBoard(board);` would output the whole board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are calling pboard with a single char:

```
pBoard(board[3][3]);
```

You should call it with an array instead:

```
pBoard(board);
```

I tested with this harness:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 3
void pBoard(char board[3][3])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    printf("  0 1 2");
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){
        printf("\n%d ", i); //After this it crashes
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j){
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char board[3][3] = {{' ',' ',' '},
                        {' ',' ',' '},
                        {' ',' ',' '}};
    // Not this! "pBoard(board[3][3]);"
    // This instead. "pBoard(board);"
    pBoard(board);

}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Sorry for the late response, my PC went out of commission shortly after I posted this question.